# Session Storage Activating All the Time

Tags: javascript

On my page I have an alert. The desired behavior is that when a user clicks the close button, the element will disappear and a key in the browser's Session Storage will be activated to prevent it from reappearing.

What's happening, however, is that the Session Storage key is placed at all times - regardless if the user clicks the close button. How might I go about having it only placed when the user clicks the button?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        let dismissed = sessionStorage.getItem("dismissed");
        let alertDiv = document.getElementById("alert");
        let dismissButton = document.getElementById("dismiss");
        if (!dismissed) {
            alertDiv.classList.remove("off");
        }

        dismissButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            alertDiv.classList.add("hide");
        });

        alertDiv.addEventListener("transitionend", function({
            target
        }) {
            if (target.classList.contains("hide")) {
                target.classList.add("off");
            }
            sessionStorage.setItem("dismissed", true);
        });
    });

</script>

<div class="ddAlert off" id="alert">
    <span class="ddAlertBtn" id="dismiss">&times;</span>
    <h5>Text</h5>
    <p>Text</p>
    <a class="ddBtn black" href="#" target="_blank">Button</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Move your `setItem` code to the `dismissButton`'s `click` event handler, instead of the `transitionend` handler?

Comment: By "activated" you mean the line with `sessionStorage.setItem('dismissed', true);` That's on a `transitionend` event handler. Are you sure there aren't some CSS transitions calling that?

Answer (score 0):

Per the `transitioned` [event specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event) the event will fire whenever a CSS transition completes on the event target. I can't tell from your code but you probably have a transition that's happening when the alert div is loaded.

Either way; you should probably set the `sessionStorage` key inside the click event handler rather than the transitioned handler. That way you can make sure it's only set on the click like you're wanting.